# Calculate the overlapping percentage two web feature service poygons

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, overlapping-features, turf

Is it possible to calculate the overlapping percentage of two polygons coming from web feature service?

I overlayed two WFS layers in my openlayers map.
The two layers have same data but collected at different timespan.So, even though they are same data, there is a change in the polygon area and shape.

I want to calculate the percentage of overlap of corresponding polygons in these two layers.

Is there any api to calculate for such cases?

I heard about Turf.js, intersect.js but couldn't get the right solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [`turf-union`](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-union):

> Find the union of geographic features
>
> `turf.union(poly1, poly2)`
>
> Takes two Polygon|polygons and returns a combined polygon. If the input polygons are not contiguous, this function returns a MultiPolygon feature.

I think it even allows for the corner case where the union of the polygons is disjoint. You will then need to determine the percentage of overlap. Take the output of `turf.union`, get its area (with [`turf-area`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_area.html)), and the area of one of your input polygons, and produce a percentage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering it turf.union is possible with the polygons returned from WFS request?
I have just the bounding boxes of the polygon, can I compute the union and find the area with that information?

Comment: Yes, it works with GeoJSON, and you should b able to get a WFS request to return GeoJSON.